# 駅データ.jpのapiを用いた駅一覧表示プログラムをphp,codelgniterで実装したいです

Tags: php, html, webapi

駅データ.jpのapiを用いた駅一覧表示プログラムをphp,codelgniterで実装したいです

駅データ.jpの中の路線APIを用いて、駅一覧表示プログラムを作成しています。使用言語はphp,フレームワークはcodelgniterです。

- 路線API(http://www.ekidata.jp/api/api_line.php)

まず、路線コードをブラウザのアドレス欄に指定したら、その路線コードの駅一覧が表示されるプログラムを作成しました。下記がそのコードです。

php(controllers)

```
<?php
 class Xml5 extends CI_Controller{
   function index($city)
   {
     $this->load->view('Xml_open_view');
     if($city != ""){
       $url = 'https://~jp/ekidata/api/l/' .$city. '.xml';
       $xmlstr = file_get_contents($url);
       $xml = simplexml_load_string($xmlstr);
       $w1 = $xml->line->line_code;
       $data = array('linecode' => $w1);
     }
     foreach($xml->station as $tmp) {
      $w1 = $tmp->station_name;
      $data = array('stationname' => $w1);
    $this->load->view('Xml5_out_view', $data);
    }   
$this->load->view('Xml_close_view');
   }
 }
?>
```

php(open_views)

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<title>xml_view</title>
</head>
<body>
```

php(out_view)

```
<?php
echo "<p>";
echo $stationname;
echo "</p>";
?>
```

php(close_view)

```
</body>
</html>
```

これで、路線コードが11612の場合、
https://web～/~/fw/xml5/index/11612(ドメインは伏せております）
とすると駅一覧が表示されました。

次に、同じ駅データ.jpの
都道府県API（http://www.ekidata.jp/api/api_pref.php）
を用いて、県番号をページ内で入力すると、路線コードが得られるプログラムを作成しました。

php(controllers)

```
<?php
class Xml6 extends CI_Controller{

     function index()
     {
     $this->load->view('Xml_open_view');
     $this->load->view('Xml6_input_view');
     $city = $this->input->post('city');
     if($city != "" ){
     $url='https://~.jp/ekidata/api/p/' . $city . '.xml';
     $xmlstr = file_get_contents($url);
     $xml = simplexml_load_string($xmlstr);
     $w1 = $xml->pref->code;
     $w2 = $xml->pref->name;
     $data = array('prefcode' => $w1,'prefname' => $w2);
     $this->load->view('Xml1_out_view', $data);
foreach ($xml->line as $tmp){
             $w1 = $tmp->line_cd;
             $w2 = $tmp->line_name;
             $data = array("linecd" => $w1, 'linename' => $w2);
     $this->load->view('Xml6_out_view',$data);
     }}
     $this->load->view('Xml_close_view');
}}
?>
```

php(input_view)

```
県番号を入力してから送信をクリックしてください:
<form method="post" action="https://~.jp/~/fw/xml6">
 <input type="text" name="city" id="city" size="60">
 <input type="submit">
</form>
```

php(out1_view)

```
<?
echo "<h1>";
echo $prefcode;
echo "<br/>";
echo $prefname;
echo "</h1>";
?>
<br>
```

php(out2_view)

```
<?
echo "<p>";
echo "<a href=https://web.~jp/~/fw/xml5/index/>". $linecd.$linename ."</a>";
echo "</p>";
?>

<br>
```

そして、この上記のxml6のコードを修正して、県番号を入力して得られた路線コード一覧にリンク要素をつけて路線コードをクリックしたらxml5を呼んで路線コードに存在している駅一覧を表示させたいです。
xml6のout2_viewの部分にa hrefを加えてリンク要素をつけてxml5を呼ぶときの方法がわかりません。
xml5は元々urlに路線コードをブラウザに指定したら表示させる仕組みなのでここからどうクリックしたら駅一覧を表示させるかに難航しています。

(追記:Xml6_out2_viewの部分を修正しました。このa href部分でindexの後に続くパスがわかりません。そこ以前の問題である場合もあります。）

Comment: phpやcodeigniterを利用せず、単純なHTMLのaタグを用いたxml5へリンクを作成することは可能ですか？

Comment: 課題ということでいまあるXml5やXml6のコードは変えられないですが、その方法でするときはどのようにすればいいでしょうか？

Comment: Web開発の基本的な考え方として、ビューの変更をする場合はまずはHTMLをどのようなものを出力したいかを考えてから、サーバサイドで必要な情報の取得と変換と出力を考えます。なのでHTMLで作成の質問をさせていただきました。再度質問しますがご自身が出力したいと考えているHTMLは書くことができますか？

Comment: リンク作成の書き方はわかります。さきほど質問内容に修正を加えました。